# How to summarize proportion in R?

Tags: r

I hope to say the proportion of the age groups (two age groups) by purchasing categories (15 categories) in order to do a Z two-sample proportion tests.

The data is like

| category | agegroup |
| --- | --- |
| Vegetable | Younger |
| Beverages | Middle and Older |
| Vegetable | Younger |
| Poultry | Middle and Older |

But  the R output shows the below errow.

```
> aggregate(x = newdata$category,               
+           by = list(newdata$agegroup),              
+           FUN = sum)
Error in Summary.factor(c(14L, 14L, 14L, 11L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 9L,  : 
  ‘sum’ not meaningful for factors
```

When I numeric the category data, it does not show a by category proportion for each age group.

```
> aggregate(x = newdata$category,               
+                        by = list(newdata$agegroup),              
+                        FUN = sum)
  Group.1       x
1 Mid_Old  728994
2 Younger 5206038
```

Comment: Your 'x' is `factor` and `sum` expects `numeric`.  Perhaps you need `newdata$category <- as.numeric(newdata$category)` coerce to numeric/integer

Comment: Do you want to know the proportions? If so, you may use `poportions(table(newdata$category, newdata$agegroups))`.

Comment: What is your expected output for the data shared? Also please share data in reproducible format. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269

Answer (score 0):

All your data is categorial ("factors" in R lingo), so you might want to use *table* instead of *aggregate*:

```
> x <- data.frame(cat=c("veg","bev","veg","pou"), age=c("young", "old", "young", "old"))
> table(x)
     age
cat   old young
  bev   1     0
  pou   1     0
  veg   0     2
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need something like this?

```
df <- data.frame(category = c("vegetable", "beverages", "vegetable", "poultry"),
                 group = c("younger", "middle and older", "younger", "middle and older"))

df %<>% 
  group_by(group) %>%
  summarise(n = n()) %>%
  mutate(freq = n/sum(n))
```

Output:

```
> df
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  group                n  freq
  <chr>            <int> <dbl>
1 middle and older     2   0.5
2 younger              2   0.5
```